# Ensuring factor levels are the same in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have two vectors of factors:

```
letters <- as.factor(c("a","b","c"))
```

and

```
letters2 <- as.factor(c("a", "c"))
```

If I run as.numeric on "letters", I get c(1,2,3). However, if I run it on letters2, I get c(1,2). Is it possible to assign factors to letters2 such that as.numeric(letters2) would give the same levels as that of "letters", i.e., c(1,3) in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: hi @bob1 thanks. But is there a way to do that more "programmatically"? I.e., instead of explicility writing levels = c(1,3), somehow deducing that from letters?

Comment: You want `factor(c("a","c"),levels = c("a","b","c"))`, keeping in mind that part of this relies on factor levels being sorted alphabetically. Another option would of course be `levels = levels(letters)`, referencing the previous factor, rather than writing them out explicitly.

Comment: @joran, correct - I have deleted to avoid confusion for others.

Comment: Thank you @joran and bob1 for your answer, it was very helpful!